# how to read file line by line and change characters if line contain specific value

Tags: bash, while-loop, fasta

I have a FASTA file (testfile.fa), which contains title lines (contain > in the beginning) and lines with characters meaning some types of nucleotides (A, C, G, T, a, g, c, t, N).

```
>chr1
cccccccccttttttttaaaa
AAAACCCCTTCCCCCCCCGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
>chr1_alt
TCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCT
gggtttccccccccccccccc
CGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGC
CCCCCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>chr2
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
TTTTTTTTTTTTATTTTTTTT
>chr3
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

I need to read this file line by line and change small characters (a, c, t, g) to N in every sequence except titles, which contain >. So I use the following code:

```
#!/bin/bash 
while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ">" ]]
    then
        echo $line
    else
        tr 'c' 'N'
        echo $line
    fi
done < testfile.fa
```

But the results are confusing:

```
>chr1
# the first line was missed
AAAACCCCTTCCCCCCCCGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
>Nhr1_alt #the character was changed but the line contains >
TCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCT
gggtttNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
CGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGC
CCCCCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>Nhr2 #the character was changed but the line contains >
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
TTTTTTTTTTTTATTTTTTTT
>Nhr3 #the character was changed but the line contains >
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTcccccccccttttttttaaaa #the first line from the first sequence comes here
```

What can be the probable reason of these problems and how can I solve them? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
$ awk '/^[^>]/{gsub(/[actg]/,"N")}1' file
>chr1
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
AAAACCCCTTCCCCCCCCGGG
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
>chr1_alt
TCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCTCT
NNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNNN
CGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGCGC
CCCCCAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
>chr2
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
TTTTTTTTTTTTATTTTTTTT
>chr3
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG
TTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Explained:

```
/^[^>]/ {               # if the record starts with anything but >
    gsub(/[actg]/,"N")  # replace all actg with N
}1                      # output
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `tr` in wrong way.

Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/sh

while read line
do
    if [[ $line =~ ">" ]]
    then
        echo $line
    else
        echo $line | tr 'c' 'N'
    fi
done < t.file
```

Comment: Thank you! But the next question appeared - when I try this code I lose the last line of my sequences and I have just something like this for ">chr3": 
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG. What can be the probable explanation?

Comment: @N.Kn  hmm... I just used the same example and got the right result. If you can make sure that you do lose the last line, now you need to debug. For example, you can remove all lines after `>chr3` and execute the script and see what will happen. Or you can remove the missing line and execute the script... Or you can modify the last line and execute the script... Enjoy your biology stuff   :D   Btw, plz notice that the filename in my script is `t.file`, whereas yours is `testfile.fa`.

Comment: thank you again:) It`s interesting, that the last line is always lost in these variants of debugging...Well, I suppose I think to continue these experiments:)

Answer (score 0):

To change all lowercase variable with an awk statement, we could use:

```
awk '{ if (substr($0,1,1) != ">") { stat="";for ( i=1;i<=length($0);i++ ) { if ( substr($0,i,1) ~ /[[:lower:]]/ ) { stat=stat"N" } else stat=stat substr($0,i,1) } print stat } else { print $0 } }' testfile.fa
```

We use awk's substr function and just print any lines with > as the first character. With the other lines, we build a variable stat changing all lower case letters to N and then printing the final stat result.

Answer (score 0):

sed is a easy way to achieve this:

```
sed -i '/^>/ !s/[actg]/N/g' testfile.fa
```

[ ] contains the characters which will be changed to N, and `/^>/ !` part ignore line starting with >

-i will overwrite the current file, without it you will get the output on the standard output.

Comment: thank you for this elegant solution! I`m afraid I know to little about sed but I really like this variant